# Removing generic kernel updates from aptitude post custom kernel install

Tags: kernel, apt

I've updated my Mint 12 system to be running a kernel built from Linus' git repo. Now, whenever I run `apt-get upgrade`, I see that `linux*-generic` are still on the update list (they're being "kept back", but they're still present).

How do I remove these from the list of packages for APT to track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're running your own kernel, you don't need to keep the official kernel installed. Remove (`apt-get remove` or <kbd>-</kbd> in Aptitude) the `linux*-generic` packages.

Comment: By *official*, you mean one packaged by Mint?